# How to give timeout for state transfer in jgroup replicated hashmap?

Tags: java, cluster-computing, concurrenthashmap, jgroups

How can i specify state transfer time out in Jgroup clustering?

```
public static ReplicatedHashMap<Integer, BaseSeatLayout> _baseSeatLayoutCache;
JChannel baseRouteCache = new JChannel(props);
baseRouteCache.connect("Master-Cluster");
client.startBaseRouteCache(baseRouteCache);
_baseSeatLayoutCache = new ReplicatedHashMap<>(channel);
_baseSeatLayoutCache.addNotifier(this);
_baseSeatLayoutCache.start(10000);
loadData()// This will load around 2 millions entry
```

Same code i am running on slave machine(or machine 2) without loadData(), But when i run that code i am getting exception for state timeout exception as 10000ms has passed and only some partial data are getting replicated. How can i change the timeout for initial state transfer?

I am using tcp protocol, my `tcp.xml` is as follow,

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups.xsd">
    <TCP bind_port="7800"
         recv_buf_size="${tcp.recv_buf_size:130k}"
         send_buf_size="${tcp.send_buf_size:130k}"
         max_bundle_size="64K"
         sock_conn_timeout="300"

         thread_pool.min_threads="0"
         thread_pool.max_threads="20"
         thread_pool.keep_alive_time="30000"/>

    <TCPPING async_discovery="true"
             initial_hosts="${jgroups.tcpping.initial_hosts:10.120.19.145[7800],localhost[7801]}"
             port_range="2" />
    <MERGE3  min_interval="10000"
             max_interval="30000"/>
    <FD_SOCK/>
    <FD timeout="3000" max_tries="3" />
    <VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="1500"  />
    <BARRIER />
    <pbcast.NAKACK2 use_mcast_xmit="false"
                   discard_delivered_msgs="true"/>
    <UNICAST3 />
    <pbcast.STABLE desired_avg_gossip="50000"
                   max_bytes="4M"/>
    <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true" join_timeout="2000"
                view_bundling="true"/>
    <MFC max_credits="2M"
         min_threshold="0.4"/>
    <FRAG2 frag_size="60K"  />

    <pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER/>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_baseSeatLayoutCache.start(10000)`

The `10000` ms is the timeout; increase it or set to `0` to wait until the complete state has been transferred.

Comment: is it possible to transfer 10GB of data in ReplicatedHashMap?

Comment: Yes. But that means every member has to have `10 * N GB` of data in its cache where `N` is the number of members in the cache. I'd instead use a _distributed_ cache rather than a _replicated_ one, where data is not copied to all members, but only to a subset. `ReplCache` is a sample (toy) impl in JGroups; Infinispan (infinispan.org) is a real implementation.

Comment: It more like i want to data in one machine(i.e. Master) form DB and copy the same data in other machine(i.e. slaves) so other machine will not load anything in cluster they'll read only from master.

Comment: Yes, that's certainly possible. I suggest use `LargeState` (part of JGroups) to test this transfer from master to slave.

Comment: is LargeState possible with TCP?

Comment: Yes: `java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true org.jgroups.tests.LargeState -props /home/you/config.xml`. The config can then include a TCP rather than UDP transport.